# Creating folders even if already exist or removing removing their content

Tags: python, performance

I have a project where, **every time I run it**, I have to:

- test if some folders exist, and create them if they don't exists.
- remove their content if the folders already exist.

This is the code that I developed to do this:

```
import os
import pathlib

def clean_Folders(directory):
    folders = ['preprocessed', 'results', 'tmp']
    for folder in folders:
        if not os.path.exists(os.path.join(directory, folder)):
            os.makedirs(os.path.join(directory, folder))
    for filepath in pathlib.Path(directory).glob('**/*'):
        try:
            os.remove(filepath.absolute())

        except:
            print('something went wrong')
```

I had another idea which is creating the folders every time I run my project (without doing the existence test nor caring about what the already contain).
Here is the code:

```
import os
import shutil

def clean_Folders(directory):
    folders = ['preprocessed', 'results', 'tmp']
    for folder in folders:
        try:
            if os.path.exists(os.path.join(directory, folder)):
                    shutil.rmtree(os.path.join(directory, folder))
            os.makedirs(os.path.join(directory, folder))
        except:
            print('something went wrong')
```

Which one of the solutions is more optimized and more professional?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second one is definitively safer, since in the first one you actually remove everything in all subfolders of `directory`, not just in the three folders you want to remove.

Some additional comments:

- I would save the result of `os.path.join(directory, folder)` in a variable, you calculate it like three times.
- Have a look at Python's official style-guide, [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). It recommends using `lower_case` both for variables and for function names, so your function should be called `clean_folders`.
- A bare `except` is basically never a good idea. And even worse is a bare `except` with the unhelpful message `'something went wrong'`. You want to either catch the exception you are looking for and handle it, or let the exception bubble to the top and halt the execution of the program. So, find out what kind of exception you actually want to catch (maybe `IOError`?). Or at least use `except Exception`, which excludes exceptions like e.g. the user pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> being caught.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and thank you another time for the **very useful** comments!